Explanation of Mathematica's result for $\frac1\pi\int_0^\omega d\Omega\ \sin(\Omega(1+n\eta))\cot\left(\eta\frac{\Omega}2\right)\eta$
I would like to understand the motivation behind the equality (given $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\eta > 0$)
$$\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\omega} d \Omega \ \sin \left( \Omega (1 + n \eta) \right) \cot \left( \eta \frac{\Omega}{2} \right) \eta $$
$$= \frac{i \eta}{2 \pi}\;\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\dfrac{e^{i \omega  (\eta  n+1)} \, _2F_1\left(1,n+\frac{1}{\eta };n+\frac{1}{\eta }+1;e^{i \eta  \omega }\right)}{\eta  n+1} \\[6pt]
+\;\dfrac{e^{i \omega  (\eta +\eta  n+1)} \, _2F_1\left(1,n+\frac{1}{\eta }+1;n+\frac{1}{\eta }+2;e^{i \eta  \omega }\right)}{\eta +\eta  n+1}\\[6pt]
+\;\dfrac{e^{-i \omega  (\eta  (n-1)+1)} \, _2F_1\left(1,-n-\frac{1}{\eta }+1;-n-\frac{1}{\eta }+2;e^{i \eta  \omega }\right)}{\eta  (n-1)+1} \\[6pt]
+\;\dfrac{e^{-i \omega  (\eta  n+1)} \, _2F_1\left(1,-\frac{n \eta +1}{\eta };-n-\frac{1}{\eta }+1;e^{i \eta  \omega }\right)}{\eta  n+1}
\end{array}\right)$$
which I obtained from Mathematica.
What would happen if $\eta = 1/N$ with $N \in \mathbb{Z}$? The previous formula does not work, since some hypergeometric functions are not defined.
Thank you.

$$\begin{align} f(n,\omega,\eta) =&\frac{i}{2 (\eta  (n-1)+1)}\cdot e^{-i \omega  (\eta  (n-1)+1)}\cdot \, _2F_1\left(1,-\left(n+\frac{1}{\eta }-1\right);-\left(n+\frac{1}{\eta }-2\right);e^{i \eta  \omega }\right)
\\& \frac{i}{2 (\eta  n+1)}\cdot e^{i \omega  (\eta  n+1)}\cdot \, _2F_1\left(1,n+\frac{1}{\eta };n+\frac{1}{\eta }+1;e^{i \eta  \omega }\right)
\\& \frac{i}{2 (\eta  (n+1)+1)}\cdot e^{i \omega  (\eta +\eta  n+1)}\cdot \frac{\, _2F_1\left(1,n+\frac{1}{\eta }+1;n+\frac{1}{\eta }+2;e^{i \eta  \omega }\right)}{\eta +\eta  n+1} 
\\& \frac{i}{2 (\eta  n+1)}\cdot e^{-i \omega  (\eta  n+1)}\cdot e^{-i \omega  (\eta  n+1)}\cdot \, _2F_1\left(1,-\left(n+\frac{1}{\eta }\right);-\left(n+\frac{1}{\eta }+1\right);e^{i \eta  \omega }\right) \end{align}$$
The integral is wrong, probably. The limit for $\omega\to 0$ seems not to exist.
The plot for a real integral is desastrous
      Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[ fI[n, 0.1, 0.2]]], {n, 0, 2}]


